# lock php file, let user can include only but can't open it

Tags: php

Is any way to lock and set password for php file.

Prevent programmer open it and change, but the file still can include();

I have some class & function, I don't want other programmer open it and steal my code, Is any way to lock it, but server can still read it?

Comment: You could use permission settings for the account that Apache (or whatever) runs on - but anyone with admin could bypass that.

Comment: Not really no. There are solutions like ioncube, but they require installation on the server and are possible to bypass. If you code is that important, dont distribute it - make its functions available over an api instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot access the PHP- Code from outside, PHP is serverside.

Comment: i know, but I work some project for some company, when I finish my work, If they hire other programmer to do it, I don't want other programmer open it.

Comment: @user2178521 Your contract with this company allows you to retain rights to the code they are paying you to write? And allows you to restrict access to it?

Comment: some of company dont sign contract with me, so i want to lock it

Comment: the only possible way to protect your sourcecode is to crypt it with tools like zend guard.

Comment: Sounds like a lawsuit waiting to happen. Plus i cant imagine they will pay you. Dont do work for companies that wont sign contracts (though i doubt any will agree to these terms anyway)

Comment: those are small business want me build a website with no contract, I lock it so make sure they will come back to me XD

Comment: Or not... they might cut their losses.